# How can i use script in sub folders on gae?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

when i was about to write a sub module for my app, i'd like to put all the stuffs in a sub folder like `/foo`, and i give the script the name `foo.py` and in it there's a

`app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/foo/', Index)])`

then it comes to

```
Fatal error when loading application configuration:
threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: foo/foo.app
  in "/home/***/workspace/***/app.yaml", line 23, column 20
```

then i set it to false, it becomes error 500

```
ImportError: Could not find module foo.foo.app
```

my `app.yaml` is like

```
application: ***
version: alpha
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /admin.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin

- url: /foo
  script: foo/foo.app

- url: /.*
  script: index.app
```

Comment: Have you made foo folder a package?

Comment: @ThanosMakris no, didn't know that, just .py files in normal folders, that's why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

finally i solved like this:

1. add `__init__.py` in the folder `foo/`, leave it empty.
2. change `foo/foo.app` to `foo.foo.app`

and it seems has nothing to do with `threadsafe`, i changed it to `true` and it's still working.

Comment: This is the right answer. @Topro you should change your choice.

Comment: @JúlioTurollaRibeiro they gave me the direction

Comment: Therefore you should mark the correct answer (yours) and bump his answer. Stack Overflow is all about fast answers for specific problems, your are obligating someone to read the entire thread this way.

Comment: You should go for the correct answer, not for the "way to get to the answer"

Comment: What does your webapp2.WSGIApplication() call look like?  I made the changes as described here, but now I'm getting a 404 instead of a 500.  The dev log console is not helping, either.

Answer (score 2):

The foo folder must be a python package so as to work. Thus, just add an `__init__.py` inside it and it should be ok.

Comment: This answer is NOT right and the right answer should go to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13006365/1052504.

Comment: It works, but you also have to change the '/' separator in the script by '.' so script: foo.foo.app

Answer (score 0):

In order to flag your folder as a package in python, the only thing you have to do is to create an empty `__init__.py` file in that folder (note two underscores on both sides of init).

Then in order to use your code from another file, you have to import the relevant file.

`import foo` where foo stands for your filename in your folder (foo.py)