# GAE app.yaml Script Handling for scripts in subdirectories (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi, webapp2, app.yaml

I am setting up a new GAE project, and I can't get my scripts in sub-directories to work.

EDIT: If I go to `localhost:8080/testing_desc.html` I don't any errors, just a blank page (view-source is blank, too).  Scripts in my root dir work normally.   There is a `__init__.py` in both the root and sub-dir.

Python script example ("/testing/testing_desc.py"):

```
import webapp2 as webapp

class DescTstPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        html = 'This should work.'
        self.response.out.write(html)

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', DescTstPage)], debug=True)
```

app.yaml:

```
application: blah
version: blah
runtime: python27
api_version: 1

default_expiration: "5d 12h"

threadsafe: false

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest


handlers:
- url: /                  <-- This one works
  script: main.app
- url: /index.html        <-- This does NOT work (??)
  script: main.app
- url: /(.*?)_desc.html   <-- Also does NOT work
  script: \1/\1_desc.app
#file not found
- url: /.*
  script: file_not_found.app
```

I have also tried a simpler version of the yaml:

```
-url: /testing_desc.html
 script: /testing/testing_desc.app
```

Comment: have you tried changing the order of handlers? putting the more specific ones on top? (just guessing)

Comment: I got the `/index.html` working by changing the `main.py` from:
`app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', DescTstPage)], debug=True)` to
`app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', DescTstPage)], debug=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here:
[How can i use script in sub folders on gae?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989956/how-can-i-use-script-in-sub-folders-on-gae/13006365#13006365)

Its not explicitly stated, but in the answer you must change `/foo/` to `/foo` in the `WSGIApplication` call, which maps to `www.bar.com/foo`.  If you want to map to `www.bar.com/foo.html` you need to change `/foo` to `/foo.*` in the `WSGIApplication` call AND the url handler in app.yaml to `- url: /foo\.html`

Answer (score 2):

When you use WSGI Pyhon27 this will work. Use a dot for the seperator :

```
-url: /testing_desc.html
 script: /testing.testing_desc.app
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list of routes to your WSGIApplicaiton call. Those routes must match whatever URL is being handled.
`('/', DescTstPage)` just matches the '/' URL to your handler. `/.*` matches all routes.

What routes are you setting in `testing/testing_desc.app`? They must match `/testing_desc.html`.

Answer (score 0):

To get my scripts working in sub-dir, I changed the `app.yaml` and `/testing/testing_desc.py` to this:

app.yaml:

```
- url: /testing.html
  script: testing/testing_desc.py
```

/testing/testing_desc.py:

```
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', DescTstPage),], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ATM I do not understand how to make the routing work with sub-dir, so I will use this.